# Desktop version to server migration

Tags: server

I have installed ubuntu desktop 10.10 and lamp server and i am using it for past 6 months. and i never use that computer for anything else.. Now i feel like removing unwanted components like media programs, open office etc which is not needed for a server. but i would like to keep the GUI just as a option for ease of use.. will there be any problem if i remove those components. i dont want to install server edition from the beginning..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to strip a desktop edition to a server edition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-strip-a-desktop-edition-to-a-server-edition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ubuntu Server Edition* is the same Ubuntu with different packages. I've installed Servers and installed the `ubuntu-desktop` package if I felt the need for a GUI on the system. I'm sure doing the reverse would work as well.

If you **want a GUI** but do not want the additional bloat that comes with Desktop edition, go ahead with it. Uninstalling Open Office, GIMP, Firefox etc should not cause any problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can do this though apart from uninstalling the office suite, which would free several hundred megabytes of diskspace, most other programs use very little disk space so uninstalling them would give you little benefits for the time spent.

Also be aware that some programs are required for Ubuntu to function properly so it's possibly to accidentally uninstall the whole desktop while trying to uninstall, for example, evolution. Just review the list of packages to be uninstalled in synaptic before proceeding - a very long list may indicate trouble

Comment: when i open process monitor i see a lot of process which are in sleep mode.. like pulse audio etc.. those save ram right.. if i remove them increase the server performance right..?

Comment: Yes, removing pulseaudio may free up some RAM which technically may increase performance (though the change may be negligibly small). What I'm saying that you may find that, say, ubuntu-desktop package depends on volume control indicator and the latter depends on pulseaudio so by trying to remove pulseaudio you may remove the whole desktop. Ubuntu packages have dependencies which are not always obvious.