# Reinstall Server over Desktop

Tags: server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to strip an desktop edition to a server edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-strip-an-desktop-edition-to-a-server-edition)

I'm a Linux noob and I've setup Ubuntu desktop on my web server thinking that the UI would help me out some.  Now I'm realizing that this probably isn't all the necessary since all my work is now done remotely to that box and I think I may have made a mistake.  I understand that the big benefit to Server is the lack of UI and extras that come with Desktop.  So my question is:

What would be the simplest/easiest way to go to Server from Desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you are looking for a simple and easy answer here but REALLY the best answer is to back your folders then do a fresh install of the server. Most of the redundant processes left over from the desktop are not needed nor are the many applications that enter into the picture when you install "say KDE-DESKTOP". All the library and binary files that follow the desktop installation clog the system.

Server management can be done in many numerous ways which do not involve a local desktop interface. My favourites are puppet and webmin but you can find ones that works for you. EBOX would come to mind and might be promising. If you find that you can't live without a desktop GUI then go lightweight like LXDE.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-gui-in-ubuntu-server.html

http://alternativeto.net/software/ubuntu-cloud/

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was afraid of.  I'm just going to leave it for now since I'm still learning and when I'm ready for production, I stand everything back up on an actual server distro.

Answer (score 2):

One quick method of doing this is in Terminal. Which can be done by pressing `Ctl + Alt + T` Enter the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-server
```

Comment: The OP wants to go FROM desktop TO a server.

Comment: My mistake, edited.