# How do I convert a desktop install into a server?

Tags: installation, server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to strip a desktop edition to a server edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-strip-a-desktop-edition-to-a-server-edition)

I installed Ubuntu with an alternate CD (for software RAID), not realizing that that installs a desktop version (or perhaps I missed a menu option?), while I wanted to install the server version.

So, how can I convert a desktop installation into a server installation. Is it just a matter of removing packages?

(I don't need it to be 100% the same as a clean server installation, just want to optimize the OS for being a server)