# How do I disable sleep on closing the lid

Tags: server, suspend

I want to transform an old laptop with a broken screen into a server.

More specifically, I want to disable the behaviour that the computer enters into sleep stand when the lid is closed.

The question elsewhere on SO ([what is the easiest way to strip a desktop edition to a server edition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-strip-a-desktop-edition-to-a-server-edition)) does not answer to my specific question.

My question is: which package do I have to remove for preventing the computer to enter into sleep stand when closing the lid.

Comment: Events like "closing the lid" are handled by acpi, so you could try to remove `acpid` and `acpi-support`. I am not sure it has anything to do with servers, but there you have it.

Comment: Two persons voted this question down. One of them, I suppose, asked me to edit the title. I did it.  How can I prevent my question to be further neglected and disappears without answer?